# App Crashs When Compressing Video When I use Flutter VIdeo Compession

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, video-compression

After I Choose A Video I try to Compess it but It Doesnt Work.

```
PickedFile pickedfile = await ImagePicker().getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxDuration:  Duration(minutes: 5),
      );
      try{
      file = File(pickedfile.path);    
      videoMediaInfo = await _flutterVideoCompress.compressVideo(
              file.path,
              deleteOrigin: true,
              quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality,
              );
```

This is the Error I Get:

```
Failed to ensure /storage/180B-0A18/Android/data/com.app.nyite/files/flutter_video_compress: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code -22)
W/com.app.nyite(26920): type=1400 audit(0.0:721): avc: granted { execute } for name="ffmpeg" dev="vdc" ino=132019 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c149,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c149,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.app.nyite
D/EGL_emulation(26920): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf6fe0920: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf731f1d0)
D/FFmpeg  (26920): Running publishing updates method
D/AndroidRuntime(26920): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(26920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26920): Process: com.app.nyite, PID: 26920
```